# Array and javascript - how to compare two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to get the value that changed when comparing two arrays?

I'll explain it better.

let's say I have

```
arr1 = [1,2,3]
arr2 = [1,2,3]
```

`arr2` get created dynamically, and the default is the same as `arr1`

When I change `arr2` to `arr2 = [0,2,3]` how can I detect the value that changed? (in this case, 1 changed to 0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know which value in which index changed, and what is the changed value, you can use Array#reduce to create an array of changes.

```js
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
var arr2 = [0, 2, 3];

function whatChanged(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr2.reduce(function(d, v, i) {
    v !== arr1[i] && d.push({
      index: i,
      from: arr1[i],
      to: v
    });

    return d;
  }, []);
}

var diff = whatChanged(arr1, arr2);

  console.log(diff);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works exactly as I needed it to. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple code snippet that you can use like this:

1) First wrap your array with `ArrayObserver`

2) Then simply use the `update` method to assign new array value

3) Keep track of the new elements in `onUpdated` callback

4) Access your array at `aObserver.array`

Let me know if the code makes sense to you and if we need to change something

```js
var array = [10, 15];
var aObserver = new ArrayObserver(array);
aObserver.onUpdated(function(newValues, oldArray){
  console.log('New values are:');
  console.log(newValues);
});

/* use the update method to assing new value of the array */
aObserver.update([10, 12]);
aObserver.update([15, 12]);

console.log('array values is');
console.log(aObserver.array);


/*
  Simple class that is holding the array and when array is updated through
  this class it will give you the new values in a callback of onUpdated method
*/
function ArrayObserver(array){
  var that = this;
  var callback = null;
  that.array = array;
  that.update = function(newArray){
  
    var newValues = [];
    /* get a copy of the old array */
    var oldValues = that.array.slice();
    
    for(var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++){
      if(!~that.array.indexOf(newArray[i])){
        /* this is a new value */
        newValues.push(newArray[i]);
      }  
    }
    
    if(callback && {}.toString.call(callback) === '[object Function]'){
      callback(newValues, oldValues);
    }
      
    that.array = newArray;
  }
  
  that.onUpdated = function(cb){
    callback = cb;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to adjust it to my particular case, thanks for now, i'll let you know if this worked or not

Comment: Yes please, I can help you if any changes are need it. I hope get the idea :)

Comment: Yes, I just need to adjust it as i'm handling the update in a different way and using this class won't really work as it's already using promises to handle updates and stuff like that, but I got the idea, i'll let you know if I get stuck, thanks again :)